# All privileges except "super"

Tags: mysql

The following statement is working as expected

```
grant all on *.* to 'foo'@'10.10.%' identified by 'bar';
```

But I want to grant all privileges except "super" privilege. I wish there was "grant all except super" syntax!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

would [revoking](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/revoke.html) the privilege immediately afterwards not do the trick?

Something like

```
revoke super on *.* from 'foo'@'10.10.%';
```